# Only 1 test class is running and TestNG execution hangs

Tags: maven, testng, jira-rest-api

I am having 2 test classes - `PostTests` and `UserTests`. I specified both of them in `testng.xml` file and when running using maven, I am seeing that all the methods of the 1st specified class in testng are running and it hangs....class 2 methods are not running. It's hanging.
Can you please help me what am I doing wrong.

**Below is my `testng.xml`**

```
<suite name="TestAll">
  <test name="post">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.vin.vinapi.PostTests"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test name="user">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.vin.vinapi.UserTests"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

**Below is output of execution**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building vinapi 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ vinapi ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/i332939/Documents/workspace/vinapi/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ vinapi ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ vinapi ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/i332939/Documents/workspace/vinapi/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ vinapi ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ vinapi ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/i332939/Documents/workspace/vinapi/target/surefire-reports
-------------------------------------------------------
T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Request URL : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
Response Code : 200
Request URL : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2
Response Code : 200
Request URL : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
```

As you can see above 2 tests from `PostTests.java` (`/posts` and `/posts/2`) executed and 1 test (`/users`) from `UserTests` started and it hanged there only

When I move `UserTests` above `PostTests` in `testng.xml`, then all tests of `UserTests` are executing and when 1 test of `PostTests` starts it hangs.

Same output when running through a command line or through eclipse.

Comment: Your xml seems fine, so it is probaly down to the actual tests themselves. Please post more regarding the actual tests. Are you using any groupDependencies? Are you running your tests in parralle or sequentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please group together the classes in one class like

```
 <suite name="TestAll">
   <test name="post">
     <classes>
         <class name="com.vin.vinapi.PostTests"/>
         <class name="com.vin.vinapi.UserTests"/>
     </classes>
   </test>
 </suite>
```

If it works fine then it seems to be connection is getting in to dead lock when processing the request.

Are the connections getting created separately in each class.

Comment: You are correct Monis, it got resolved after changing the access specifier for client object.  Earlier same connection is used to make calls of both classes. After changing it to make separate connection, it worked. Thanks bro